# What are the connection properties to send mail to an account in Microsoft Outlook using MS Exchange Server?

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I am trying to send an email from MS Outlook account with the following class:

```
public class MailSender {

public MailSender() {}

public static boolean send(String hostSmtp, String senderAddress,
        String toAddress, String subject, boolean isHTMLFormat, StringBuffer body,
        boolean debug) {

    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", hostSmtp);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    //properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    session.setDebug(debug);
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // BODY
        MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
        if (isHTMLFormat) {
            mbp.setContent(body.toString(), "text/html");
        } else {
            mbp.setText(body.toString());
        }

        multipart.addBodyPart(mbp);
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(msg);            
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        System.out.println(">> MailSender.send() error = " + mex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

But when I use the class in a jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import = "pe.com.bn.PRFI.general.MailSender"%> 
<html>
<head>
<title>EnviarCorreo</title>
</head>
<body>
<%  
boolean result = MailSender.send("smtp.bn.com.pe", "email1@bn.com.pe",
"email2@bn.com.pe", "Test Mail", false, new StringBuffer("Hello"),true);

out.print("Result of sending the message : " + result);
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

shows me the following exception:

> [15/10/14 19:30:58:126 GMT] 00000026 SystemOut     O DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.3.1
>   [15/10/14 19:30:58:293 GMT] 00000026 SystemOut     O DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>   [15/10/14 19:30:58:302 GMT] 00000026 SystemOut     O DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
>   [15/10/14 19:30:58:302 GMT] 00000026 SystemOut     O DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.bn.com.pe", port 25
>   [15/10/14 19:30:58:305 GMT] 00000026 SystemOut     O >> MailSender.send() error = javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
>     nested exception is:
>       class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.bn.com.pe, port: 25;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Are the connection properties are well specified?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have one line in Spanish in an otherwise English post?

Answer (score 0):

First, correct this [common mistake](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

If that doesn't help, and you're running in a server with a security manager, you may need to [grant your application the security permissions to connect to the mail server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#securityManager).